# ¿Como promediar varias filas en R?

Tags: r

quiero promediar en R varias filas... por ejemplo

Tengo una matriz. En dicha matriz tengo profundidad real, concentración Nitrogeno y fosforo, y profundidad nominal  (5m, 15m...tengo cada 10-15 m hasta los 150 m)

Es decir, para una concentración de N tengo hasta 10-9 datos, por profundidad nominal...y quiero promediar esa concentración de nitrogeno por profundidad nominal hasta los 150 m.

Ya intente con lapplay, aggregate, etc.. pero no soy muy buena en R.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más cómoda y sencilla de promediar una matriz o incluso un `data.frame`  es mediante [`colMeans()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html):

```
mat <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

colMeans(mat)

[1]  3  8 13 18 23
```